# Google Calendar API CalendarQuickstart.java throwing an IllegalArgumentException something about web or installed,

Tags: google-calendar-api

When I run CalendarQuickstart.java as a Java Application I get an IllegalArgumentException Stack Trace. It appears to be a Security Issue. Something to do with web or installed?

I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

Here is the Stack Trace:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:121) at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.getDetails(GoogleClientSecrets.java:82) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:197) at googlecalapi.CalendarQuickstart.getCredentials(CalendarQuickstart.java:71) at googlecalapi.CalendarQuickstart.main(CalendarQuickstart.java:83)

Comment: Please email fix to me at jfries1234@gmail.com